# How can I input an integer seed for producing random numbers using the rand crate in Rust?

Tags: random, rust, random-seed, rust-crates

In a Rust project, I want to generate **reproducible** random numbers based on a integer seed as I'm used to in Java.

The documentation for `Seed` in the `rand` crate states:

> Seed type, which is restricted to types mutably-dereferencable as u8 arrays (we recommend [u8; N] for some N).

Does this mean an integer seed is not possible? If it is possible, how can I use `StdRng` with an integral seed?

Comment: why the generated number should be the same even with the same "seed", Rust have its own implementation, java too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this function out: [`StdRng::seed_from_u64`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html#method.seed_from_u64)

It comes from the `SeedableRng` trait, which `StdRng` implements.

For example:

```rust
let mut r = StdRng::seed_from_u64(42);
```

Note that this will give you reproducible random numbers as long as you use the same build on the same platform, but the internal implementation of the `StdRng` is not guaranteed to stay the same between platforms and versions of the library! If reproducibility between platforms and builds is important for you, then look at crates such as `rand_chacha`, `rand_pcg`, `rand_xoshiro`.

Answer (score 6):

I will share my own answer because I had to search a little more to achieve my goal.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.7.3"
rand_distr = "0.3.0"
```

**Code:**

```rust
use rand_distr::{Normal, Distribution};
use rand::{Rng,SeedableRng};
use rand::rngs::StdRng;

fn main() {

    let mut r = StdRng::seed_from_u64(222); // <- Here we set the seed
    let normal = Normal::new(15.0, 5.0).unwrap(); //<- I needed Normal Standard distribution

    let v1 = normal.sample(&mut r); // <- Here we use the generator
    let v2 = normal.sample(&mut r);
    let n1: u8 = r.gen();   // <- Here we use the generator as uniform distribution
    let n2: u16 = r.gen();
    println!("Normal Sample1: {}", v1);
    println!("Normal Sample2: {}", v2);
    println!("Random u8: {}", n1);
    println!("Random u16: {}", n2);
}
```

**My Output:**

```
Normal Sample1: 12.75371699717887
Normal Sample2: 10.82577389791956
Random u8: 194
Random u16: 7290
```

As [michaelsrb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2992101/michalsrb) mentioned on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59021270/9300379)
Please note that this will guarantee the same values on different runs on your (build - Platform), the same seed used in a two months later version, could give different values.