# How to produce reproducible pseudo-random numbers based on a seed for all platforms with the rand crate?

Tags: random, rust, random-seed

This is a follow-up to [How can I input an integer seed for producing random numbers using the rand crate in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020767/how-can-i-input-an-integer-seed-for-producing-random-numbers-using-the-rand-crat). In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59021270/4593433), it is stated that if reproducibility across builds and architectures is desired,

> then look at crates such as `rand_chacha`, `rand_pcg`, `rand_xoshiro`

The same is stated in the [documentation](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html) for `StdRng`:

> The algorithm is deterministic but should not be considered reproducible due to dependence on configuration and possible replacement in future library versions. For a secure reproducible generator, we recommend use of the rand_chacha crate directly.

I have looked at these crates, but I have not found out how to use them for my use case. I am looking for a small sample showing how one of these crates can be used for generating a sequence of pseudo-random numbers, that are always the same for a given seed.

Comment: Uhm, `rand_chacha` should provide you with the sequence from a seed iirc.

Comment: Basically, all the RNG structs in `rand_chacha` implement the `SeedableRng` trait, so you can call `ChaChaRng::from_seed()` or `ChaChaRng::from_seed_u64()` to initialize the RNG with a seed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example using [`rand_chacha::ChaCha8Rng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_chacha/struct.ChaCha8Rng.html):

```rust
use rand_chacha::rand_core::SeedableRng;
use rand_core::RngCore;
use rand_chacha; // 0.3.0

fn main() {
    let mut gen = rand_chacha::ChaCha8Rng::seed_from_u64(10);
    let res: Vec<u64> = (0..100).map(|_| gen.next_u64()).collect(); 
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f4b8b8488c38fb3769e2da40f1a2659)